# How to stop regex expression at certain string and capture the sub string?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I want to capture the string in between the two matches of the regex expression.

I have this string

```
var testingString="NO Lettuce nNO Onions nNO Tomato nNO Ketchup NO  Grilled Onions NO baked Sub Zapps"
```

The regex expression I am using now is:

```
let matches = self.regexMatches(for: "([^\\snNO]+|[NO]\\S+([a-zA-Z0-9_\\w+])+\\S)", in: testingString)
```

I am getting output as:

```
Lettuce
Onions
Tomato
Ketchup
Grilled
Onions
baked
sub
zapps
```

But I want the output to be as:

```
Lettuce
Onions
Tomato
Ketchup
Grilled Onions
baked sub zapps
```

This is the regexMatches function I am using:

```
func regexMatches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        var tempResults = results.map { result in
            (1..<result.numberOfRanges - 1).map { result.rangeAt($0).location != NSNotFound
                ? nsString.substring(with: result.rangeAt($0))
                : ""
            }
        }
        return tempResults.flatMap{$0}
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do some of the values have the ' n' and some don't?

Comment: Do you want to match anything preceded by `NO` or `nNO`? Does the uppercase matter?

Comment: It seems to me you are way overthinking this task. Why not just search for a much simpler pattern — `NO` possibly preceded by `n` — and replace with something you can then split the string on? Then trim the split components and you're done.

Comment: Yes Uppercase and lower case matters.

Comment: I am very beginner in programming. Can you please help me how to do that?

Comment: You may try `let pattern = "\\b(?:(?!(?:\\B-|\\bn?)NO\\b).)*"` but it is highly inefficient.

Comment: `(?:n?NO\s+)((?:(?!\s+n?NO).)*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this much more simply. Just replace `nNO` or `NO` with a split character, and split on it. Now trim out the whitespace, remove any empty splits, and you're done.

```
let s = "NO Lettuce nNO Onions nNO Tomato nNO Ketchup NO  Grilled Onions NO baked Sub Zapps"
let pattern = "\\bn?NO\\b"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let s2 = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: s, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: s.utf16.count), withTemplate: "|")
let arr = s2.split(separator: "|", omittingEmptySubsequences: true)
    .map{$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)}
// ["Lettuce", "Onions", "Tomato", "Ketchup", "Grilled Onions", "baked Sub Zapps"]
```

Comment: What about using only `let pattern = "(\\s*n?NO\\s*)"; let replaced = testingString.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "\n", options: .regularExpression)`? No need to use the introduced separator. The regex might be more consuming, indeed, to check.

Comment: Well, @Larme, of course you could do that, but then you've just pushed the split back one step. Sooner or later the OP _does_ want to split (his printout is just an artifact), so we may as well do it up front.

Comment: @Larme What I'm _really_ trying to do here is split. So taking that as a given, the problem I'm trying to solve is that Swift `split` doesn't take a regex pattern, unlike languages with "real" string handling, like ruby. My approach is just a workaround for that. If this were ruby, I would have split _without_ any introduced separator.

Comment: What if I have dash before NO? like -NO Grilled Onions-. How do I remove this?

Comment: Then you asked the question wrong. I can only answer the question you actually asked. Providing a correct spec is _your_ problem.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I did not realized about this issue before. Do I have to make another post ?

Comment: Well it would be better to write your own solution now that you've been shown the way. It's not our job to write your code for you, but to teach you how you might approach the problem.

Comment: @AmritaSapkota `let pattern = "(?:\\bn?|\\B-)NO\\b"` should work then.

Comment: I am doing this:
let pattern = "(\\s*n?NO\\s*)|(\\s*-n?NO\\s*)" 
let testingString="NO Lettuce nNO Onions nNO Tomato nNO Ketchup -NO Grilled Onions- -NO baked Sub Zapps"
I am getting output as :
Lettuce
Onions
Tomato
Ketchup
Grilled Onions-
baked sub zapps
 I want to remove that dash after Grilled Onions as well.

Comment: @AmritaSapkota Regex is not a magic, it's a regular expression. You will have to make up your mind about what you want exactly.